# reverse unix sort on non-existent field

Tags: sorting, unix, command-line

I have a largish file with lines like this: (^I represents a tab, $ end-of-line)

```
2^IElaeocarpus williamsianus^I48$
4^I$
6^I$
8^I$
10^I$
12^I$
14^IElaeocarpus hookerianus^I73$
16^IElaeocarpus kirtonii^I111$
20^I$
22^ITetratheca juncea^I66$
42^IMalagasy giant rat^I401$
```

and I want to sort the lines so that those with the highest number in the 3rd field (i.e. after the 2nd tab) come first, i.e.

```
42^IMalagasy giant rat^I401$
16^IElaeocarpus kirtonii^I111$
14^IElaeocarpus hookerianus^I73$
22^ITetratheca juncea^I66$
2^IElaeocarpus williamsianus^I48$
4^I$
6^I$
8^I$
10^I$
12^I$
20^I$
```

(I don't care about the order of the lines with no field 3). So I assumed something like the following would work

```
sort -r -t $'\t' -k 3,3n myfile
```

but it doesn't (GNU sort, OS X 10.9). I feel I'm being stupid. What's the correct incantation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a modifier to your `-k` parameter, not the command line parameter.
So something in these lines should do the trick:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 3,3nr myfile
```

Comment: exactly what I was missing. *Thank you*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it isn't `n` what you want, but `g`.

```
sort -t $'\t' test.txt -k 3.2gr
```

The dot specifies in the key at which character to start comparing.

As favoretti pointed out, what you want to reverse is by that column, so you apply the modifier there.